# Копирование из stringstream в array - Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

```
std::stringstream stream;
std::array<char, 1000> buffer;
long value = 100; // 8 bytes

stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(value));

std::copy(stream.str().begin(), stream.str().end(),&buffer[0]);

stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(value));

std::copy(stream.str().begin(), stream.str().end(),&buffer[0]); // Segmentation fault
```

stl_algbase.h

```
template<bool _IsMove>
    struct __copy_move<_IsMove, true, random_access_iterator_tag>
    {
      template<typename _Tp>
        static _Tp*
        __copy_m(const _Tp* __first, const _Tp* __last, _Tp* __result)
        {
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      using __assignable = conditional<_IsMove,
                       is_move_assignable<_Tp>,
                       is_copy_assignable<_Tp>>;
      // trivial types can have deleted assignment
      static_assert( __assignable::type::value, "type is not assignable" );
#endif
      const ptrdiff_t _Num = __last - __first; // здесь значение отрциательное 
      if (_Num)
        __builtin_memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
      return __result + _Num;
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `std::stringstream::str` возвращает **новый** объект `std::string`.

В выражении `std::copy(stream.str().begin(), stream.str().end(),&buffer[0]);`
 `stream.str().begin()` будет итератором на начало одной строки, а `stream.str().end()` будет итератором на конец уже совершенно другого объекта-строки.

Это тоже самое, если к примеру в алгоритм поиска в последовательности отправить начало одного вектора и конец другого

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<int> b;
std::find(a.cbegin(), b.cend(), 0);
```

Следовательно решение - запомнить объект перед вызовом `copy`:

```
auto str = stream.str();
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), &buffer[0]); // можно buffer.data() вместо &buffer[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку `stream.str()` возвращает строку, а не ссылку - как вам уже пояснили, это разные строки.

Но можно воспользоваться `rdbuf()`, который позволяет работать прямо с буфером:

```
std::copy(stream.rdbuf()->str().begin(), stream.rdbuf()->str().end(),&buffer[0]);
```

Так можно обойтись без создания лишней строки.